# Sentiment analysis and fasttext: import error

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, fasttext

I want to run some sentiment analysis using `FastText`. However, I have always got errors during the declaration of libraries and no example and tutorial within the web seems to be able to fix this.

I have tried to follow the steps described here: https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/tree/master/python#installation

but since the beginning, i.e. since

```
import fasttext
from fasttext import train_unsupervised
```

I have been getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-193c2ffe3856> in <module>
      1 import fasttext
----> 2 from fasttext import train_unsupervised
      3 
      4 # Skipgram model :
      5 model = fasttext.train_unsupervised('data.txt', model='skipgram')

ImportError: cannot import name 'train_unsupervised' from 'fasttext' (/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fasttext/__init__.py)
```

I am using Python 3.7 in Jupyter Notebook. I would need FastText to analyse the sentiment of some Italian texts. 
I went here: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-models.html but I have not understood what I should download.

I really hope you can help me with this.

Comment: may be in newer version of fasttext, train_unsupervised in removed or name is changed. try using old version of fasttext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code on a clean Python 3.7 conda environment should work after installing fasttext with pip (`pip install fasttext`).

If you do that, you should see in a Linux console with

```
pip list | grep fasttext
```

that your `fasttext` version is 0.9.2 (the current one today).

In addition, upon installing the `wget` package with pip, the code below should get you started for sentiment analysis using one of the trained models (Amazon reviews) in the page that you linked:

```
import wget
from fasttext import load_model

wget.download("https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/supervised-models/amazon_review_polarity.bin", 'model.bin')

model = load_model("model.bin")

model.predict("This movie sucks") # see how output changes!
model.predict("This band is great")
model.predict("I just feel OK about this.")
```

If model size is an issue, try replacing the model with a compressed one:

```
wget.download("https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/supervised-models/amazon_review_polarity.ftz", 'model.ftz')

model = load_model("model.ftz")
```

You can also refer to https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html to train a model on a custom dataset instead.

Comment: Hi Davide, thank you for your answer. I upgraded the version to the latest one, as you suggested. Then I installed wget and tried to run the code you posted. However I got the following error: `Exception: fastText: Cannot load model.bin due to C++ extension failed to allocate the memory`. Do you know the reason why I have got it?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind could be that you don't have enough RAM available for this task. Freeing up some may help. If you have a Google account you could also run the code in a Jupyter notebook in the cloud/colab.

Comment: Thank you Davide. Do you know how much RAM I should need for this task? Lastly, there is something small dataset that I could use for checking if it works or not, rather than running the code in a Jupyter Notebooko in the cloud?

Comment: Hi @LucaDiMauro, looks like that could be a separate question :) On the memory size bit, I edited the question to provide some more guidance. If you need to test the model with a dataset, check out the [nlp library](https://github.com/huggingface/nlp) and try out 

`import nlp;
sentiment = nlp.load_dataset('sentiment140')`

Comment: Thank you so much Davide. I will try it with this new dataset (and open a new question in case I will be having some issues). Thanks a lot